# Multiple number of objects unknown before runtime as locks for a Java thread

Tags: java, multithreading, locks

I have a set of resources which are instances of a `Resource` class. There are jobs in the system coming in at runtime. 
Each job requires a set of these resources, and must have exclusive use of all the resources it needs for it to proceed. 
That is, in order for a job to be able to start, it has to acquire locks of all the resources it needs, and release all these locks it acquired once it's done. 
So, a job can't start its processing unless all the locks of all the resources it needs are available.

The resources a job needs aren't known before run-time. The resources list a job needs is passed in to its constructor as a `Collection` `ArrayList<Resource>`.

One way of doing this is, in the `run()` method of each job thread, i can synchronize on the locks of all resources that "this" job needs.

```
synchronized (resource1) {
    synchronized (resource2) {
        ...

    }
}
```

But this is hardcoding and can't be done since resources the job needs are only known at runtime.

Another way I can think of is putting the resources in a collection structure so that, when the lock of that collection is acquired, the locks of all the entries in that collection are also acquired and ths not available to anyone else.

There is `Collections.synchronizedList()`. However, it only locks the `List`, not the objects in the list.

How can this be done?

TIA.

Answer (score 1):

How about using a loop, you iterate over the list of `Resources` available at runtime and then acquire the lock on the objects per iteration, here is an example where I demonstrate this with the `Object` class:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
       List<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();
       list.addAll(Arrays.asList(new Object(), new Object(), new Object()));
       Runnable run = () -> {
           for(Object o: list) {
               synchronized (o) {
                   System.out.println("Current thread " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                   System.out.println(o.hashCode());
                   try {
                       Thread.sleep(2000);
                   }catch (InterruptedException ie){
                       ie.printStackTrace();
                   }
                   //do something useful
               }
           }
       };
       new Thread(run, "t1").start();
       new Thread(run, "t2").start();
       new Thread(run, "t3").start();
       new Thread(run, "t4").start();
 }
```

When one thread has acquired the lock on a particular object other threads will wait for it, but they are free to acquire lock on the next available object from the for-each loop.

Answer (score -1):

You could write your own implementation for the List interface and lock your ressources when they are queried in the list.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html